# Dynamically loaded class missing members at runtime

Tags: java, reflection

I'm trying to load a class dynamically and iterate through the declared fields within it. I'm finding that occasionally, a field that I have recently added to the dynamically loaded class is missing.

The catch (and yes, I understand this is not really best practice) is that the dynamically loaded class is modified by the program just before it is loaded.

Specifically:

1. A "template" (for lack of a better word) .csv file is read (this can be updated in between runs of the program)
2. A POJO class is generated based on that template (this is the class we want to dynamically load, and should be re-written on each run to reflect changes in the template)
3. A `Class` object is created based on the full qualified name of the class we just made
4. We iterate through the declared fields within the class.

I've tried making the function that actually generates the POJO class return a value to ensure that everything is running in order (not that that would ever happen but at this point I'm deeply lost).

I've also tried deleting the POJO entirely between runs of the program, to no avail.

The only potential resolution that I've found is running the whole program twice in a row, which seems to somehow make the changes to the POJO class fully settle.

This seems to indicate that in some way, when I load the generated class based on the qualified name, the previous version of the class (prior to any edits to the template) is loaded.
The real question is why? Is it possible to ensure that I am loading the absolute most recent version of a class?

Comment: What are you trying to do? Sounds like a [xy problem](https://xyproblem.info/). Can you add your code as a [mcve]?

Comment: Instead of hooping through the "Generate Class -> work on it reflectively", consider using a `Map<String, Object>`.

Comment: @Robert The software I am working on consists of ~40 copies of nearly-identical code, where the general flow is SQL query -> conditional formatting -> print to txt file. The only places that these pieces of code differ is the SQL query, the conditions applied, and the order of output fields. My goal is to eliminate this duplication by defining the conditions and field order in a "template" csv file. To that end, I am generating an entity class that maps the SQL query results to field names in the output, then passing the entities to a printer class that reads the template and print accordingly

Comment: @JohannesKuhn I am currently iterating through the members of the class because the order is important, I rely on the data being in a specific order. I could potentially use a LinkedHashMap, though I'm not sure that that would resolve my current issue.

Comment: Fields in a class do not have an order, so they are the wrong tool in that case.

Comment: If you are not doing anything with the fields, just formatting them, can you get away with not having a data object and instead just put everything in a hash and use a templating system for the final output?

Comment: Obviously, a `LinkedHashMap` would do but if you have to process a lot of rows it would be more efficient to have a single `List<String>` for the column names (which never change while processing a table) and a `List<Object>` for each row holding the values with indices corresponding to the column name list. But maybe, you can drop the over-engineered abstraction layers and just implement a loop over the `ResultSet`, performing the formatting and writing to the text file. Makes a total of 100 to 200 lines of code, depending on the complexity of the actual formatting. No code generation needed.